# Testing the result of an action in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, ember-data

I've asked this question on IRC and didn't get much response so i thought i'd ask it here.

Essentially I'm trying to test the result of an action using the Ember Testing helpers but my assertion is happening too soon, and in fact the action handler doesn't even get called!

Here is a working JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vobegeta/11/edit

I say working but of course one of the tests is failing but it should be passing. This is a subset of the bits from my own app where this system is working in non testing mode.

p.s. open the developer console and you should see console log when the event actually fires.

Comment: Can we close or delete this question? This wasn't really related to Ember, since the solution just involved fixing typos in your sample code.

Comment: The type part wasn't the most important thing, i think it would be useful to keep so people would know to make sure they are clicking the right element

Comment: I still don't see how that is specific to Ember.js. Needing to click the correct element to trigger a click handler is a requirement for testing any events on elements, regardless of what code generated the elements. At the very least the question should be revised and retagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 minor mistakes:

- Typo in `App.ChatsControler = ...` (should be `App.ChatsController`, with double `l`)
- The correct selector for clicking the link is `.chats-filter-pills li:contains('Missed') a`, not the `li` itself, as the action handler is registered on the `<a>` element.

Have a nice hacking! :)